# Can we predict the behavior of a linear composition of known functions?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, roots, interval-arithmetic

Let
$$f(x) = a_1f_1(x)+...+a_Nf_N(x)$$
be a function composed of known continuous and smooth functions $f_1...f_N$ and $a_1...a_N$ some constants. the term "critical point" is defined as the roots of derivative. But in here, let us define the vector of critical points as:
$$x_c = [x_{c1},x_{c2},...,x_{cK}]$$
which contains all zeros of the functions $f_1...f_N$ and their derivatives, sorted in ascending order: $x_{c1}<x_{c2}<...<x_{cK}$; that is, the points $x_c$ are either roots or the local minima/maxima of the consisting functions.

I want to isolate the intervals that contain one and only one critical point of $f(x)$. Is it possible if $x_c$ are at hand? Also is it correct to say that in an arbitrary interval of $[x_{ci},x_{ci+1}]$, there exists only one critical point?

Comment: note that critical points and local extreme values are not the same thing. For example, $f(x)=x^3$ has no local extreme value, but $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: I would say "linear combination" or "superposition", not "composition".

Comment: @Taladris yes, I forgot to mention that, thanks.

Comment: @mr_e_man what is the difference?

Comment: Superposition is $f(x)+g(x)$. Composition is $f(g(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; there doesn't need to be any simple relationship between the roots/critical points of $f(x)$ and the roots/critical points of the $f_i$. Consider
\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= \sin(x) + 2x\\
f_2(x) &= \sin(x) - 2x\\
\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 &= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Then $x_c = \{0\}$ but of course $f(x)$ has tons of critical points (and roots).

Answer (score 1):

As exemplified by @user7530 you need further assumptions before progress can be made. In the extreme case of $f_i : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_i(x) = \exp(x)$ for $i=1,2$ and $a_1 + a_2 = 0$ you have $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, while $f_i = f'_i$ has no zeros at all.

Comment: Can give some examples of "further assumptions"?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmard. I would need to know what you are trying to accomplish. As your question is currently phrased, it is ill-posed. That may be because you discarded some background information. I have no way of knowing what information you have omitted.

Comment: please see also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572094/can-we-predict-the-zeros-and-local-extremums-of-a-linear-combination-of-sinusoid