# Can we predict the zeros and local extrema of a linear combination of sinusoidal functions?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, roots

Consider the following function:
$$f(x) = a_1\cos(\omega_1 x)+...+a_N\cos(\omega_N x)$$
where the $\omega_n$ and $a_n$ s are known constants.
in some particular situations the expression can be explicitly summed but in general, I am wondering if we can somehow at least predict or estimate the zeros and the local extremums of the resultant function.

Comment: I'd assume it should be at least as hard as finding the zeros of an $N$-th order polynomial

Comment: @a_student How are the two problems similar?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi, check out Weierstrass substitution, for example. https://math24.net/weierstrass-substitution.html.